# Importing python modules from different directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I have a flask app with essentially the following structure:

```
app/
  __init__.py
  myapp.py
  common/
    tool1.py
    tool2.py
  web/
    __init__.py
    views.py
    api/
      api_impl.py
  worker/
    __init__.py
    worker.py
    tasks.py
```

I initialize in `myapp.py` an important object I use in several places and I can access it from `common/tool1.py` and `web/api/api_impl.py` with `from myapp import object`. I've been able to use `tool1` and `tool2` in multiple places in `web/` and `myapp.py` importing with `from common.tool1 import tool1_def`.

Other relevant facts are in `myapp.py` there is an `import web` statement for the blueprints and `app/__init__.py` and `worker/__init__.py` are empty. `web/__init__.py` contains the blueprint definitions for the routes.

I can run the app with gunicorn with no issues, but when I try to run my worker with `python app/worker/worker.py` I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp'`. The `worker.py` is trying to import the same object defined in `myapp.py`.

I just don't understand why I can run the app and it works but when I try to run the worker it doesn't! I'm definitely not fully understanding the import system in this case and everything I've read online doesn't seem to fully clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your working imports imply that the project root is the app folder. As such you need to lunch your worker from this folder (or add it to PYTHONPATH environment variable)

```
python worker/worker.py
```

Or

```
python -m worker.worker
```

In addition your `__init__.py` in the app folder should be removed as app is not a package but a project root.

Comment: Thanks. I removed __init__.py and it didn't change anything, which I suspect is good. setup.py is in the parent folder from app but it does say the packages are app.web and app.worker (now that I removed __init__.py). The worker ran successfully with `python -m worker.worker` but not with `python worker/worker.py` from the app folder. Any idea why?

Comment: One thing, after removing `__init__.py` from the app folder when I run setup.py it doesn't find any of my packages anymore. Should I move setup.py inside the app folder or manually define them?

Comment: you need to decide what is your project structure. If you want app to be a package it is fine but then all the imports should be like: import app.worker.worker

Comment: there are other more advanced ways like relative imports but from my experience imports from the root package downwards is the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

One method we use regularly for development and debugging (but also works in production) is the following.  You can add this to each (offending?) module, or all modules if you choose.

```
import os
import sys

# Add your project root to sys.path.
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))

from common import tool1
from common import tool2
from worker import worker
etc ...
```

Here you are adding your project root to `sys.path`.  When performing imports, Python starts by looking through `sys.path` for the module you're trying to import.  So here, you are adding your project root as the first item in `sys.path`.

Another advantage is these imports are explicit to your project.  For example, if you have a local `workers` module which you want to import, but also have a `workers` package in `site-packages`, this will look in your local project first.